# Nifi-1.0.0 and Crate.IO

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-nifi

Crate database offers a jdbc driver through which I should be able to connect to Crate from Nifi using DBCPConnectionPool controller service. So I did that, I get a connection, the ConvertJSONToSQL processor is able to get the columns from the Crate database but when I get to the PUTSql processor I get the following error:

```
FlowFileHandlingException: transfer relationship not specified
```

The thing is that I have a SUCCESS, FAILURE, RETRY relationship defined. It just throws a ProcessException in the onTrigger() method.

Any ideas how can I make it work ? 
As soon as the jdbc driver is compatible it should work, but ...

Comment: FlowFileHandlingException points to a programming mistake. Could you post the rest of the stack trace and any other logging associated with the PutSQL near the exception?

Comment: It's a standard processor from NiFi, PutSQL, which when I use it with the postgresql's jdbc driver, it works just fine.
I get a WARNING: Processor Administratebly Yielded for 1 sec due to a processing failure.

and the ERROR which I've specified.

Comment: Yup I know it's a standard processor and it appears theres a path of logic that leaks a flowfile without giving a transfer relationship. So there's no log messages saying something went wrong beforehand?

Comment: Also what version of NiFi are you using?

Comment: So the full error message is:

`PutSQL[id=....] failed to process session due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.FlowFileHandling:
StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=..., claim=StandardContentClaim[resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=..., container=default, section=325], offset=1010666, length=395], offset=0, name=file_name.txt.avro, size=395] transfer relationship not specified`

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a bug in PutSQL that is hiding an issue either in the JDBC configuration, SQL statement, or something else. Using the standalone JDBC driver with valid SQL INSERT statements, I was able to PutSQL working with Crate.

Can you double-check your connection information and SQL statement(s)? Also if you can reproduce and want to share the SQL and/or connection info (JDBC URL, e.g.), please feel free, it could help get to the bottom of the PutSQL bug that is hiding another issue.

Comment: Connection information
`Database Connection Url: jdbc:crate://10.5.5.2:4300/schema_name
Database Driver Class Name: io.crate.client.jdbc.CrateDriver
Database Drive Location(s): file:///path/to/nifi/lib/crate-jdbc-standalone-1.13.1.jar`


SQL statement:

`INSERT INTO schema_name.my_table (transdate, transtype, salestype, account, custname, custadd1, custcity, custstate, custzip, custcountry, custemail, custphone, accessusername, accesspassword, currencyid, ma) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`

Comment: I see 16 column names but 18 parameters

Comment: Also it appears you may have put the Crate JDBC JAR into NiFi's lib/ folder, that's discouraged as it can mess with the rest of NiFi. Better to put it somewhere else on the file system and point there in your Database Connection Pool.

Comment: I've made a mistake when editing the sql statement. I've verified in the flowfile, and the number of columns coresponds with the number of parameters. I'll try to move the jar into other folder, outside of the lib/ directory.

Comment: I've put the crate jdbc driver in another directory, gave it permissions, but the I have the same problem.

Comment: Solved the issue. I had an id column, primary key, in the database, but didn't autoincrement, so basically that was the problem.
I was inserting my columns & expected the id to autoincrement.

Comment: Were you including an ID in the insert statement? I'd like to try to reproduce because there is definitely a bug in how that is being handled

Comment: I did not have the ID in the INSERT statement, that was actually the problem. In the case where I was using Postgresql, that wasn't an issue, because when I was insertinga record the ID field was autoincrementing, in the case of the CRATEIO db, the ID field wasn't set to autoincrement.
To reproduce set a table in CRATEIO with an ID column, and on nifi, insert all the columns in the statement except the ID column.